# insert into select mysql

Tags: mysql

MySQL newcomer here. I've built a database to contain environment variables. Each value is associated with a unique `class`, `designation`, and `variable`, each of which has a definition table. When I add a new variable, I need to copy a foreign key from each definition table into a new table, `variable_mappings` as well as add a value. The `variable_mappings` table looks like this:

```
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field          | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id             | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| value          | varchar(512) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| designation_id | int(11)      | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| class_id       | int(11)      | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| variable_id    | int(11)      | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Right now the command to add a variable looks something like this:

```
INSERT INTO variable_mappings (variable_id, designation_id, class_id, value)
    SELECT variable_definitions.id as 'variable', 
           designation_definitions.id as 'designation', 
           class_definitions.id as 'class' 
    FROM variable_definitions 
    JOIN designation_definitions on designation_definitions.name='development' 
    JOIN class_definitions on class_definitions.name='av-control' 
    WHERE variable_definitions.name='CONFIGURATION-DATABASE-MICROSERVICE-ADDRESS';
```

MySQL complains that there's no default value for `value`. What's the best way to add a row to `variable_mappings`?

Answer (score 0):

Try remove the value from the INSERT statement column list:

```
INSERT INTO variable_mappings (variable_id, designation_id, class_id)
SELECT variable_definitions.id as 'variable', 
       designation_definitions.id as 'designation', 
       class_definitions.id as 'class' 
FROM variable_definitions 
JOIN designation_definitions on designation_definitions.name='development' 
JOIN class_definitions on class_definitions.name='av-control' 
WHERE variable_definitions.name='CONFIGURATION-DATABASE-MICROSERVICE-ADDRESS';
```

or add a field in the SELECT statement

```
INSERT INTO variable_mappings (variable_id, designation_id, class_id, value)
SELECT variable_definitions.id as 'variable', 
       designation_definitions.id as 'designation', 
       class_definitions.id as 'class',
       blablabla as 'value'
FROM variable_definitions 
JOIN designation_definitions on designation_definitions.name='development' 
JOIN class_definitions on class_definitions.name='av-control' 
WHERE variable_definitions.name='CONFIGURATION-DATABASE-MICROSERVICE-ADDRESS';
```

Answer (score 0):

`INSERT INTO SELECT` statement require the `SELECT` statement to return the same amounts of columns as the amount of columns in the parentheses. In your case, you are asking MySQL to insert into 4 columns, yet your `SELECT` statement only returns 3 columns. a quick way to go around this is to add `NULL` in your `SELECT` like so:

```
INSERT INTO variable_mappings (variable_id, designation_id, class_id, value)
SELECT variable_definitions.id as 'variable', 
       designation_definitions.id as 'designation', 
       class_definitions.id as 'class',
       NULL /* default value for the 'value' column */
FROM variable_definitions 
JOIN designation_definitions on designation_definitions.name='development' 
JOIN class_definitions on class_definitions.name='av-control' 
WHERE variable_definitions.name='CONFIGURATION-DATABASE-MICROSERVICE-ADDRESS';
```

the other alternative is to simply remove `value` from the list of columns to insert to. Since the column already has a default value of `NULL` in the DDL, that's the value it will be set to.

```
INSERT INTO variable_mappings (variable_id, designation_id, class_id)
SELECT variable_definitions.id as 'variable', 
       designation_definitions.id as 'designation', 
       class_definitions.id as 'class' 
FROM variable_definitions 
JOIN designation_definitions on designation_definitions.name='development' 
JOIN class_definitions on class_definitions.name='av-control' 
WHERE variable_definitions.name='CONFIGURATION-DATABASE-MICROSERVICE-ADDRESS';
```